# How to clear read input when using tput rc?

Tags: bash, tput

```sh
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

sc=$(tput sc)
rc=$(tput rc)

printf "$sc%s\n" "Type word"
read -r word
printf "$rc%s\n" "Type word (again)"
read -r word_confirmation

$ ./test.sh
Type word (again)
test
```

I would like `test` to be cleared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tput ed` clears the screen from the current cursor position to the end of the screen (broken on macOS, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556123) answer).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tput sc
printf "%s\n" "Type word"
read -r word
tput rc
tput ed
printf "%s\n" "Type word (again)"
read -r word_confirmation
```

[tput clear screen](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php#clearing-the-screen)

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out. The above code doesn't appear to work... the whole screen is cleared... not just `test`. Would you mind adjusting your code block to expand upon my code?

Comment: Apparently, there is a [bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556123) on macOS that breaks `tput ed`.

Comment: Do you use macOS and does `tput cd` work on your machine? btw my output for `printf '%q' "$(tput ed)"` is `$'\E[J'`

Comment: I was developing a script on macOS. `printf '%q' "$(tput ed)"` outputs `''` on macOS Catalina. `printf '%q' "$(tput cd)"` outputs `$'\033'\[J`.